# Passing a character from R to C- Memory allocation

Tags: c, r

I am not able to understand how this is happening in my code. My actual code is too long but the following code gives an overview of what I am doing.

My C code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char * str[]={"abc", "cde", "apple", "cat", "happy"};

void copychar(char** chars)
{
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
    {
        strcpy( chars[i], str[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

I compile this code and run my R code.

My R code is as follows:

```
dyn.load("E:\\StackOverflow\\Code.dll")
.C('copychar', character(5))
```

My output here is following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "abc"   "cde"   "apple" "cat"   "happy"
```

What I do not understand is how is the memory allocation done in this case. I pass 5 empty characters from my C and get back the strings from C. For each string in the character vector what is the memory allocated i.e how may letters strings can I pass from C to R using this method?

Comment: When doing `strcpy( chars[i],` you are passing `char**` to function expecting `char*`. Please enable warnings on your C compiler to avoid mistakes like these.

Comment: @user694733: I saw the warning in the compiler for this. I couldn't understand how this is working. Also, could you suggest any other way in which I could get back the vector with strings in R from C?

Comment: As it's now, C code invokes *undefined behaviour*, so anything can happen. Are you sure that your function prototype shouldn't be `void copychar(char** chars)`? This would fix the C side of things; I don't know the details of R side.

Comment: @user694733 Doing that also I get the same output. I actually want to understand how am I getting this output and what are the limitations? What is the actual memory allocated to each string in the vector by R. Do you have any idea about that?
I also edited the code as per your suggestion.

Comment: I don't know R to give you the details, but considering that it kind of worked, C code probably got address of the first element of array of pointers to arrays of chars (similar type to `str`).